# Sorting a table according to another table

Tags: sql, perl, oracle, dbix-class

I have a table A.

```
|----+----|
| P  |  S |
|----+----|
| p1 |  1 |
| p2 |  7 |
| p3 | 14 |
| p4 | 23 |
| p5 |  1 |
|----+----|
```

and table B

```
|----+----|
|  S |  C |
|----+----|
|  1 | 21 |
|  5 | 21 |
| 23 | 21 |
|  1 | 30 |
|  7 | 90 |
|----+----|
```

I need to sort table A.

Sorting order:

```
A. TableA.S exists where  (TableA.S = TableB.S) and TableB.C = 21
B. TableA.P
```

Final Output:

```
|----+----|
| P  |  S |
|----+----|
| p1 |  1 |
| p4 | 23 |
| p5 |  1 |
| p2 |  7 |
| p3 | 14 |
|----+----|
```

This needs to be converted to DBIx::Class query.

I tried following:

```
Select tableA.P, tableA.S
from tableA left join tableB on tableA.S = tableB.S
where (tableB.C = 21 or tableB.C is NULL)
order by tableB.C, tableA.P
```

But I am missing somewhere to get the result where tableB.S is '7'.

Thanks.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Where are you stuck? What's your real question?

Comment: Why does P4 come before P5 in your desired output?

Comment: APC: I like to define sorting order properly. So if TableA.S exists somewhere as TableB.S then I like to sort by Table.P. ( Modified the sorting order section).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sorts by `A.P` for all the records in A a matching record is found in B then by `A.P` for the other records.

```
 SQL> select A.P
       , A.S
from A 
     left join B        
        on ( A.S = B.S 
             and B.C = 21)
order by nvl2(B.S, 'ZZZZZZZZZZ', A.P), A.P
/

  2    3    4    5    6    7    8  
P           S
-- ----------
p1          1
p4         23
p5          1
p2          7
p3         14

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can actually avoid the use of `CASE` or related equivalents (such as `COALESCE(...)` and the db-specific related functions):

```
SELECT TableA.p, TableA.s
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
       ON TableA.s = TableB.s
          AND TableB.c = 21
ORDER BY TableB.c, TableA.p
```

Why does this work?  Default behavior of Oracle (and some other dbs) is that `null` sorts as the "greatest" value (some consider it the "lowest" value, which would be trivial to fix in this case).  So first rows with a value in the given column (which is a constant value) are given, then those without...